# Override Method onCreateView Causing Error

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to put the TimePicker fragment into the tab class I created, but the following override method is causing issues:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);

    // Set OnClick Listener
    findViewById(R.id.setBtn).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

I have not put anything into the MainActivity class, but rather in the tab class. As I am new to Android Studio, I am not sure if avoiding to use the MainActivity was the way to go.

P.S - here is the error:
[image]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Not really sure - there is nothing specifically stated about the actual error other than that it has something to do with the override method above.

Answer (score 1):

You should return view at the end of onCreateView method.

Replace

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
```

With

```
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
```

At the end of onCreateView method

```
return view;
```

Comment: It still doesn't work... do you have any other solution in mind because I have exhausted all the possibilities to fix this issue on my end.

Comment: I cannot post the complete code on here. Can I send you the project file?

Comment: https://cf-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/fernandesk1_cardiff_ac_uk/EqCF4Nfq8opHqEXm5l8B-FoB38mivAMq-n7SW2q0skRmaQ?e=OfNixp

Comment: I looked into your code. You are making tab1 an activity.You should be making it a fragment. right?

Comment: Yes. I want to be able to place the digital clock on tab1 with two buttons which set the alarm and cancel it. Tab2 will have show if the alarm (task) has been completed by any of the registered users. I do not know how to separate the fragment from becoming an activity.

Comment: Then you should extend tab1 with fragment. I will rectify the code and send it to you

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nlanphusKRa4r73p_w3W5-KXAVweA3LP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Above is the link to your tab1 corrected. Hope it should work

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Usman. This program is nearly complete now! There is one issue regarding the fragment_timer which I do not know how to fix: View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timer, container, false); . Will I have to create a new fragment?